# Unity objects are displayed outside the program

Tags: unity-game-engine

Does Unity have a way to display objects outside the program?
I hope to be able to make an external toolbar to control the display of objects in the program.
Thanks.

Comment: To clarify, Are you trying to show the objects from a camera in an editor window?

Comment: Hello, I want to make a full screen program, and then the custom toolbar can be placed on the extended screen for external control.

Comment: and what will you do with this toolbar ? the editor itself is not enough ? and don't get if you want a dev toolbar or a game toolbar :/

Comment: I would like to have a menu that can appear outside the game window, allowing the user to control the appearance or disappearance of objects from the outside.

Comment: I don't think having a multi-window game is built in. You could create another window through script (c# window forms app). Try reading this conversation https://forum.unity.com/threads/multiple-window-game.475407/

Comment: Thanks, I'm building another window to control it through Multi-display.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MultiDisplay.html